# Is there a limit to ask question per day or per week?

Tags: support

May I know if there is any limit/ restriction on the number of questions posting on this site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[There are some limits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide/164900#164900), but from what I can tell, that's not what happened in your case. You hit a question ban, which you can read about in the Help Center:

- [Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans)

There is some helpful information there about what to do next.